# Using .htaccess to rewrite urls with ID: "Page not found"

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite some urls by using the .htaccess file in a WordPress environment. I have a WordPress page called "offerta" with two parameters, one of them is a custom ID that I use to generate content.

so, an example url is: http://www.riccionelastminute.it/rlm/offerta/?id=15&titolo=my-title

and I would like it to be: http://www.riccionelastminute.it/rlm/offerta/my-title-15/

this is my .htaccess right now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rlm/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rlm/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

After some research, I tried to add this rule right after the last Rewrite Rule, but it redirects to a 404 page:

```
RewriteRule ^offerta/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/$ offerta/?id=$2&titolo=$1
```

I'm not used to play around .htaccess and I'm not an expert.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last `RewriteRule` has the `L` flag which means that [no other rules are applied after it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l). What you need to do is add your rule **before** the last one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rlm/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^offerta/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)/$ offerta/?id=$2&titolo=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rlm/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but unfortunately it still gives me a Page not found error.